# Getting skipped frames with RxAndroid on a simple call

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

I'm implementing in a LauncherActivity (with just a loading indicator) an Observable (Single) from RxJava library to login with the previously recorded users credentials.

The activity is very very simple, and yet I get a skipped frames warning (40ish), both on my phone and on emulator, and I can't figure out why (though sometimes it doesn't show up).

**Here is the code :**

```
public class LauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (UsersUtils.hasCredentialsRecorded(this)) {
            getAccessToken();
        } else {
            login();
        }
    }

    public void getAccessToken() {

        Callable<Token> callable = new Callable<Token>() {

            @Override
            public Token call() throws Exception {
                final Map<String, byte[]> credentials = UsersUtils.getCredentials(getApplicationContext());

                Token token = OauthCalls.getToken(new String(credentials.get(UsersUtils.PREFERENCES_USER_KEY)),
                        new String(credentials.get(UsersUtils.PREFERENCES_PASS_KEY)));
                return token;
            }
        };

        Single.fromCallable(callable)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<Token>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                        if (token == null) {
                            login();
                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        login();
                    }
                });
    }

    public void login() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }        
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Looks fine except you don't change thread to main thread after callable is executed. Check what takes so much time. I would add `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` after `subscribeOn()` and see if it it changes anything. Maybe startActivity is expensive call and generates lag. Record timestamps and check what is the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I tried to observe on the main thread but it did nothing, and furthermore I don't need to do anything on the main thread.
It's possible that I can't do much about it because my phone is extremely slow but as you advise I will investigate more and check memory and resource usage.
One thing, how do I change back to main thread after executing callable ? Thanks !

Comment: You change back to main thread by calling `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

Comment: That's what I thought you meant :) Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't see anything that would bog down the main thread directly. Maybe the initial class loading of RxJava components takes longer.